# Chaining Knockout Custom Bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, custom-binding

I have a Knockout custom binding handler that I want to call the foreach bindings functionality on within it and then call a callback function afterwards. I keep getting a "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. " error now as I try to do this.

My custom binding is pretty simple (typescript):

```
/// <reference path="knockout.d.ts" />
ko.bindingHandlers["postForeach"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (!allBindingsAccessor().postForeachCallback)
            throw "Callback not defined for postForeach binding!";

        //call foreach init functionality
        ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            //call foreach update functionality
            ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            //call callback
            allBindingsAccessor().postForeachCallback();
    }
};
```

Is there something I am missing in constructing this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Callback Function

```
self.populateMainContentWindow = function () {
                    var dataTable = $(this.tableId).dataTable();
        dataTable.fnDestroy();

                // create the datatable
                        var actualTable = this.jQuery(this.tableId);
        if (actualTable.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // create the data table with options
        var newDataTable = actualTable.dataTable(this.options);

        // always set the width afterwards
        actualTable.css("width", "100%");
            };
```

Data Bind Signature (which is within a 'with' binding):

```
postForeach: array, postForeachCallback: $parent.viewModel().populateMainContentWindow
```

Comment: I haven't used TypeScript, which you appear to be using, but it looks like your binding is calling it's own init again.  Have you tried putting a console.log in there to see if it is calling it's own init?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle which repros your issue! Your code with Michael answer works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/94epu/

Comment: What is `this` in `populateMainContentWindow`? Based on the code, it would be the binding object returned from `allBindingsAccessor`, which won't have `tableId`, `jQuery`, or `options`. So that function shouldn't be working.

Comment: If your binding is `foreach: BatchDefinitions, postForeach: { postForeachCallback: $parent.etlViewModel().populateMainContentWindow }`, it won't work. Your other version, `postForeach: BatchDefinitions, postForeachCallback:  parent.etlViewModel().populateMainContentWindow` looks like it should work.

Answer (score 6):

Knockout uses the return value of `init` to determine whether it should process the element's descendants. You can either just return the value of the `foreach.init` function or specifically return `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` from your `init` function:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    if (!allBindingsAccessor().postForeachCallback)
        throw "Callback not defined for postForeach binding!";

    //call foreach init functionality
    return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

Comment: Should there be something special as well for the update call?

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue...I still get the same problem "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: Based on the information and code you've provided, this will solve the problem. Maybe there's another problem somewhere elese. Can you also give us the code for the "postForeachCallback" function and the Html code where you've got the "postForeach" binding?

Comment: @MichaelBest This answer really helped me out, thanks!  I should mention for others that it worked for my issue with the `if` binding as well.  All I needed to do was return the result of the `init` call from my overriden binding.  Also, remember to pass **ALL** of the parameters to the parent binding.

Answer (score 2):

**Variant 1**
I think your current binding looks like

```
data-bind="foreach: someArray, postForeach: ..."
```

You can setup `value` for `foreach` binding inside `postForeach` binding. e.g:

```
data-bind="postForeach : 
           {postForeachCallback : function()
                                  {
                                    alert('After')
                                  },
           foreach: someArray}" // this is your old foreach
```

binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["postForeach"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (!valueAccessor().postForeachCallback)
            throw "Callback not defined for postForeach binding!";

        //call foreach init functionality
        return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].init(element, valueAccessor().foreach, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            //call foreach update functionality
            ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].update(element, valueAccessor().foreach, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            //call callback
            valueAccessor().postForeachCallback();
    }
};
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2YAS/)

**Variant 2**
This varian view model (`innerViewModel`) inside view model. This view model is binded with `with` binding.
Now `data-bind` lookls like

```
data-bind="postForeach : true, postForeachCallback : $parent.postCallback, foreachEx: values"
```

View looks like

```
<div data-bind="with: innerViewModel">
   <ul data-bind="postForeach : true, postForeachCallback : $parent.postCallback, foreachEx: values">
       <li data-bind="text: val"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UnPVw/)

Comment: My data-bind looks just like "data-bind="postForeach: array, postForEachCallback: function(){ definedFunction() }", even after changing my data bind to match what you have I get the same error.

Comment: it is within a 'with' binding if that makes any difference

Comment: @BenNelson second variant with `with` binding is added

Comment: still doesn't work...i get a 'undefined is not a function' error

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it has anything to do with the code you posted.  Rather, it looks like there are multiple calls to applyBindings, and two of them are hitting the same element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/bFKuL/
(look in the console for the error)

```
var vm = {
    Name: "George"
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Markup:

```
<div data-bind="text:Name"></div>
```

To get around this, don't call applyBindings on the same element twice.  To help you figure out exactly how to do this with your code, we'd need to see more of your code, such as a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.